# How to separate 'Plot Area' from the 'Data Table' in an Excel Pivot Chart (standard line chart)

Tags: excel, datatable, pivot-chart

Whenever I add a 'Data Table' element to my Pivot Chart (Standard line chart type), it is combined with the X-axis or is overlapping the X-axis. This is preventing me from changing the alignment or any other formatting of the X-axis as it is combined with the 'Data Table'. If I remove the 'Data Table' element, I am able to format the X-axis as required.

How do i include a data table AND be able to format the x-axis i.e. adjust the alignment of the x-axis text etc? (Specifically relating to a Pivot Chart (standard line chart) with the X-axis being dates)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as I do not have enough reputation but could you tell as to what are you trying to format after adding the data table.

By default the data table will combine with the axis to provide better look. Its a default functionality. Help me understand as to what are you trying to format with the X Axis?

Edit: I am able to Format the axis even after adding the data table. I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: Hey mate. I am using Office Pro 2013. The x-axis of the line graph (pivot chart) are dates. After adding the data table, I am unable to actually see the graph's x-axis as the top of the data table (which also contain dates) is either overlapping the axis or replacing it. Therefore, if i try change the x-axis label alignment or anything else, no changes occur. Might help to mention that i have also moved the pivot chart to its own chart sheet.